# Different headers for post and get request with axios,create?

Tags: javascript, react-native, asynchronous, axios, fetch

```
export default myAPI = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'myapiurl',
  // headers for post reuqest
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': 'o987WyyzM7ktyEVzP4dakCdIY12LprtJU8qZHs5Xs0s',
  },
  // headers for get requests
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Accept: 'application/json',
  },
});
```

Basically want conditional headers depending on weather a post or a get request is being made.

Comment: Please clearly mention the issue that you are facing related to this

Answer (score 1):

You can use different `headers` based on HTTP method in this way:

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'https://api.example.com';
axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = AUTH_TOKEN;
axios.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
```

As explained here: https://github.com/axios/axios#global-axios-defaults